# How can I center my wrapper while having bottom:0px?

Tags: css, position, centering

I want to have the bottom of my wrapper touching the bottom of the browser at all times. But I don't know how to center it horizontally.

url: http://arabic001.com

```
  #wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    bottom:0px;
    width:1110px;
    height:675px;
    border:1px white solid;
}
```

Thanks to John I solved the issue of centering it horizontally. But now the bottom is acting really strange. It switches between being too low (part of the wrapper is eaten up by the bottom of the browser) or there is extra space at the bottom even though the code says bottom:0px;. here is my new code:

```
#wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    bottom:0px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-555px;
    width:1110px;
    height:675px;
    border:1px white solid;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
left:50%;
margin-left:-555px;
```

Pad it half way and subtract half the width to the left margin.
http://screensnapr.com/v/dZvq1K.png

Comment: thank you! that centered it beautifully. But now even though I wrote bottom:0px; there is still some space at the bottom when I set the browser on a bigger size. Is there a way around that?

Comment: CORRECTION: I just checked it again and it is doing the opposite of what I just described. The bigger the browser the bigger the chunk that is eaten up at the bottom! How do I solve that problem?

Comment: something really strange is happening. I am going to describe it (edit) it in my question above.

Comment: You could try setting the height of the wrapper to 677px

Comment: I had tried fooling around with the height before and that doesn't seem to be the solution. I think something else is going on. I am using a different computer than the one I normally use. I just checked it on a mac and it is perfect. Maybe the browser that I am using on this computer is different... Also a related problem is that not only is the bottom messed up on this browser, but also the rest of the positioning is off. The navigation bar and the sub menu are pushed down so that nothing is aligned properly. I guess I have a browser compatibility problem here. Any ideas? many thanks

Comment: My last idea is to add 2px margin to the bottom of the wrapper